# Is there a way to display floats correctly in Dreamweaver CS5 Design View?

Tags: css, css-float, wysiwyg, dreamweaver

I'm setting up templates and snippets for my design team, they don't want to fuss with this that and the other. I figure fair enough, and everything's mostly going well, except that I'm experiencing difficulties in displaying floats in Design view.

It's important to note that Live Preview displays beautifully, as does my output content, but in edit mode on design view... the floats aren't quite right. Developer note: I am using this to apply standardised 'clearance' across browsers and most platforms:

```
@media screen {
    /* Clear fix */
     .clearfix:after {
          content: ".";
          display: block;
          height: 0;
          clear: both;
          visibility: hidden;
     }
     .clearfix { display: inline-block; }
     /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
     * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
     .clearfix { display: block; }
    /* End hide from IE-mac */
}
```

I've attached two screenshots with annotations, instead of trying to convey this in text.

EDIT: o dern, i dont have enough points to paste in screenshots, here's a link to two combined screenshots: http://codefinger.co.nz/_etc/dw_screenshot_a_and_b.gif

Any and all help appreciated, thanks.
- d

Comment: How about posting some code? I bet 95% of developers never used design view.

Comment: I didn't really feel the need to add further to this easwee, the pasted class is a re-usable one, is fairly standard, and non-clearing floats are generally well understood.

The solution over at Adobe, while not absolutely ideal, was to add markup:

<div style="clear: both; width: 100%; height: 1px;"></div>

So I've done that, and also given the div tag an alt attribute: alt="PLACEHOLDER", since I sweep for and remove placeholder tags/attrs in situations like this, before moving into client-ready production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my last comment if interested.